# What data type is used on variable names? And how can I shortcut assignments to multiple variables? C++

Tags: c++, string, loops, for-loop, variables

I was wondering if there is a way to shortcut this:

```
int main(){
    int number1,number2,number3,number4,number5,number6;
    number1=0;
    number2=0;
    number3=0;
    number4=0;
    number5=0;
    number6=0;
}
```

If variable names were strings I would do something like this:

```
int main(){
    int number1,number2,number3,number4,number5,number6;
    string number="number";
    for(int i=1;i<7;i++){
        number<<i=0;
    }
}
```

Not sure though if I can use "<<" here but I think you get the point. It would be a "+" in C#.

This is just an example. But there are some points that I want to shortcut this. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Normally you will use an array.

Comment: Tag with a *specific* language. There are already **many** duplicates; in some languages it is simply not realistically possible (as in C/C++/Java eg.) and in others it is frowned upon, or only as last-resort, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think in terms of *variables with related names*, think in terms of *data structures*, where in this case you mean *array*:

```
std::vector<int> number(6, 0);
```

Where that creates [an array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with `6` entries, each containing `0`.

You can use these like:

```
number[i]
```

Where `i` is just an index between 0 and 5.